# How to process this calculation with Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I would like to make a real-time filter using Flink.
the idea is to have a value by key stored as accumulator and to calculate a ratio versus the total sum for all keys.

I know it's impossible to share state between keyed operator thus I'm not able to calculate the total value

example :

1. k1,1
2. k2,3
3. k1,1
4. k2,5
5. k3,0

I need to calculate on the stream the following ratio 
1/1 , 3/4, 2/5, 8/10, 0 (is always filtered) etc...

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom stateful operator with the following state:

```
int totalSum;
Map<Key,Ratio> map;
```

Every event increments the total sum, then update the map according to the event key.

Example:

After 1st event `k1,1` your state is:

```
totalSum 1
map 
   k1, 1/1
```

And you emit the event: `k1, 1/1`

======

After 2nd event `k2,3` your state is:

```
totalSum 4
map 
   k1, 1/1
   k2, 3/4
```

And you emit the event: `k2, 3/4`

[.. continue]

Comment: Do you have any sample how to implement such custom operator ?

Comment: @RichardGrossman https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/dev/stream/operators/process_function.html

Comment: I'm going to write one and see Thanks

Comment: @RichardGrossman as a kind reminder, you might accept and upvote the answer